# Using tensorflow reduce_sum on tensorflow placeholder results in random error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am implementing a Replicated Softmax Model in tensorflow. Given a batch of data, I have to sum along the rows (yielding a column vector) and I have to take an outer product of this with the hidden units bias. 
Using `tf.matmul(tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_sum(visible_units, 1,keepdims=True)), tf.expand_dims(self.h, 1))` causes this error `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): In[0] is not a matrix`

Here `visible_units` is a `tf.placeholder` (dimension: batch_size x n_visible_units) and `self.h` is hidden layer bias (n_hidden_units).

The error doesn't make sense and seems completely unrelated. 
If I replace `tf.matmul(tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_sum(visible_units, 1,keepdims=True)), tf.expand_dims(self.h, 1))` with just `self.h` my code runs fine.

EDIT:
`tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_sum(visible_units, 1,keepdims=True))` generates a 1-D tensor so just had to reshape this.

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: Turns out I was feeding a 1-D tensor to tf.matmul. I fixed it.